# Is there a way to execute tools based on the names of feature classes or raster names?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder

I would like to execute Zonal statistics as a table on two different raster layers that share a common element in their name.
For example: one layer is called x_1980,
and another layer is called y_1980.

I want to do something like;
if the year is the same do the zonal statistics
    and output Z_1980_zonal_stats
    where x_year is the input raster
    and y_year is the input value raster
    and Z_year is the output_table.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Have you found arcpy.ListRasters()?

Comment: Could you please supply more information on your data structure?  I am having a difficult time envisioning what you are trying to do.  Why would you require an automated approach on this as opposed to an out-of-the-box approach?

Comment: Since Python is in your tags, I assume you've attempted a script. How far have you got? This is definitely possible, but hard to help without a starting point. Basically, you need to list your rasters, loop through, parse each name, find the matches, substitute the matches into the tool (as is common in many arcpy scripts).

Comment: as phloem was saying, a [list](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000003w000000) with a wildcard something like: rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*_1980, "ALL") and then function(rasters)

Comment: To answer these Questions:
Data Structure: all rasters are in a file geodatabase.
   the Files have the same naming conviction a prefix  
   followed by the year, for both the input zones, and the 
   input value rasters.
I have attempted a script but I am not sure how I can loop through all the names and find the matches. This is the part that I am really struggling with.

Comment: Do you have multiple years and are your years in a particular order, for example, do you have all years between 1980 and 1990? Or are they sporadic, for example, 1980, 1981, 1985, 1989, etc. ?

Comment: @ew_gis the years are in a sporadic order

Answer (score 1):

This code has not been tested, but it should get you going in the right direction:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.workspace = "Path/To/Workspace.gdb"
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#Static Variables
field = "VALUE"

#Build list of years 
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("x_*, "ALL")

#Loop through names, get year and use it to select rasters and name output table
for r in rasters:
    year = r.name
    year = year.replace("x_", "")
    inRaster = "x_" + str(year)
    valueRaster = "y_" + str(year)
    outTable = "z_" + str(year)
    ZonalStatisticsAsTable(inRaster, field, valueRaster, outTable, "NODATA", "MEAN")
```

Since your years are sporadic, the above code will make a list of all of your "x_" rasters, get the name of the raster and remove the "x_" part, leaving only the year.  It will then use that value to select the in and value raster, and name the out table.